# how to achieve msal azure ad b2c in react native

Tags: javascript, typescript, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

```
  const config = {
    issuer:
      'https://zoomonlineb2c.b2clogin.com/zoomonlineb2c.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_MobileSignup_in/v2.0',
    clientId: '83c5579e-d55b-4647-8c93-b66ee2961f49',
    redirectUrl:
      'com.ztg.zoomonline://com.ztg.zoomonline/android/callback/', // the redirectUrl must end with a slash
    scopes: ['openid', 'offline_access'],
  };

  const auth = await authorize(config);
  console.log('auth :>> ', auth);
```

Need to handle the azure ad b2c in react native

Comment: Can you provide more details on what you are trying to get?

Comment: Are you trying to **Sign in** to **ad-b2c** using **msal** in react native in typescript?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: yes i am trying to Sign in to ad-b2c using msal in react native in typescript

Comment: can you please help me to achieve this @DasariKamali

Comment: @Nalin Sakthivel Check this **GitHub** link https://github.com/michaelburch/react-native-aad-b2c-sample.

Comment: @Nalin Sakthivel Check this [GitHub](https://github.com/vi-nu/aadb2c/tree/master/React-Native-IOS-Android-AppAuth-B2C) also

Comment: Thanks @DasariKamali
 I have completed this task, and it's working. Can we modify the UI in that template?

Comment: @Nalin Sakthivel Can you tell me which Github code worked for you from the above I shared?

Comment: github.com/michaelburch/react-native-aad-b2c-sample. this one @DasariKamali

Comment: @Nalin Sakthivel Yes, you can change UI in that template.

Comment: may i know how i will

Comment: @@Nalin Sakthivel You can add the HTML data in the Home.js code that you want to get in your UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting my comments as an answer benefits the community.

According to this [GitHub](https://github.com/michaelburch/react-native-aad-b2c-sample?tab=readme-ov-file) document, we can implement MSAL Azure AD B2C in React Native.

**Code :**

**Login.js :**

```js
import React from 'react';
import {
  ActivityIndicator,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  Alert,
} from 'react-native';
import {LoginView} from 'ad-b2c-react-native';
import * as SecureStore from './SecureStore';

export default class Login extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.webView = React.createRef();
  }
  onLogin = () => {
    const {setAuthenticated} = this.props;
    setAuthenticated(true);
  };
  onFail = (err) => {
    Alert.alert(err);
  };
  onBack = () => {
    this.webView.current._backHandler();
  };
  spinner = () => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.spinner}>
        <ActivityIndicator animating={true} />
      </View>
    );
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.body}>
        <View style={styles.frame} />
        <LoginView
          style={styles.webView}
          appId="<client_ID>"
          redirectURI="https://<tenant_name>.b2clogin.com/oauth2/nativeclient"
          tenant="rnb2csample"
          loginPolicy="B2C_1_susi"
          secureStore={SecureStore}
          renderLoading={this.spinner}
          onSuccess={this.onLogin}
          onFail={this.onFail}
          ref={this.webView}
          scope="openid offline_access https://<tenant_name>.onmicrosoft.com/<scope_id>/read"
        />
        <View style={styles.frame}>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={this.onBack}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Back</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  body: {
    flex: 1,
    width: '100%',
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    opacity: 0.92,
  },
  frame: {
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  webView: {backgroundColor: '#222222', flex: 1},
  button: {
    margin: 10,
    padding: 5,
    borderRadius: 5,
    backgroundColor: '#222',
    width: 90,
    height: 30,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  buttonText: {
    color: 'white',
  },
  spinner: {
    backgroundColor: '#222222',
    height: '100%',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

**Logout.js :**

```js
import React from 'react';
import {Alert, ActivityIndicator, View, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import {LogoutView} from 'ad-b2c-react-native';

export default class Logout extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.onSuccess = this.onSuccess.bind(this);
    this.onFail = this.onFail.bind(this);
    this.spinner = this.spinner.bind(this);
  }
  onSuccess() {
    const {setAuthenticated} = this.props;
    setAuthenticated(false);
  }
  onFail(reason) {
    Alert.alert(reason);
  }
  spinner() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.spinner}>
        <ActivityIndicator animating={true} />
      </View>
    );
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <LogoutView
        style={styles.body}
        onSuccess={this.onSuccess}
        onFail={this.onFail}
        renderLoading={this.spinner}
      />
    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  body: {
    flex: 1,
    width: '100%',
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    opacity: 0.92,
  },
  spinner: {
    backgroundColor: '#222222',
    height: '100%',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```